# Python - byte read/write and bitwise AND

Tags: python, byte

I thougth I knew Python enough to program a basic chip8 emulator, but it seems I was wrong.

I'm basically having problems to read/write bytes to and from memory.
At a certain point in the program, I need to read to a variable a single byte I've already read from a file and stored in a list.
This is how I read from the file:

```
byte = rom.read(1)
memory.append(byte)
while byte:
    byte = rom.read(1)
    memory.append(byte)
rom.close()
```

At a certain point in the program, I need to get a byte from memory, AND it with 0x80 shifted by certain numbers (to extract single bits), so I use:

```
for i in range(h):
    p = ord(memory[addressI + i])
    for j in range(8):
        if(p & (0x80 >>j)) != 0:
        ...
```

It works fine for a while but then I get this error out of nowhere:

```
 (...)p = ord(memory[addressI + i])
 TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

If I simply don't use the ord funcion I get this error, as expected:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I think I get this error because at some point in the program I store the BCD of a stored value in in the memory. I guess it replaces the byte type previously stored for an int one.

```
data = registers[sNum>>8]
memory[addressI] = data/100
memory[addressI + 1] = (data/10) % 10
memory[addressI + 2] = data % 10
```

Possible solutions are:
1 - properly store the int calculated as a single byte in the list that "emulate" the chip8 memory
2 - use a function or a miracle instead of ord() that gets whatever the data is and stores it as a single byte

Any help would be appreciated.
By the way, I'm using windows and tested this code in both Python 2.7.2 and 3.2.2.

Comment: "you are doing it wrong" - first of all, please, use a python array instead of a list to hold your data in memory. Arrays are in the standard library module named "array"

Comment: Well, you diagnosed the problem yourself and offered valid solutions, so I'm not sure what your question is. What I'd do is store only numbers in the memory list/array.

Comment: @jsbueno Well, I guess I'll try it.

Comment: @interjay My question was more like: "How do I do it?"... As far as I know, I cant store only numbers in the memory list because I read all data from a file and they won't simply become integer just using the int() function. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Bruno: What I meant is to call `ord` after reading from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes the most sense to keep the type in your list consistent, which you can do fairly easily by passing the integers that your are calculating into the `chr()` function (which is the reverse of `ord()`):

```
data = registers[sNum>>8]
memory[addressI] = chr(data/100)
memory[addressI + 1] = chr((data/10) % 10)
memory[addressI + 2] = chr(data % 10)
```

However here is an alternative, which is to create a function that returns the right thing whether the argument is an `int` or a byte.

```
ord_ = lambda c: c if isinstance(c, int) else ord(c)
```

and then change the line in your for loop to this:

```
p = ord_(memory[addressI + i])
```

So now if that item in the list is an integer, `ord_(memory[addressI + i])` will return it unchanged, but if it is a byte then it will return the result of `ord()`.

**edit:** The empty string in your list may be there because of your read loop, try changing it to the following:

```
byte = rom.read(1)
while byte:
    memory.append(byte)
    byte = rom.read(1)
```

This should prevent the situation where the last time through the loop `rom.read(1)` returns an empty string and then immediately appends it to `memory` before checking the `while` condition.

Comment: I really thought your solution would work but it didn't, unfortunately. Now I get an error like "TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found". Thank you.

Comment: @BrunoO.c. - See my edit, I think you read loop is the cause of the empty string.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I was just about to rewrite my whole code perhaps in another language.